# Issue loading assembly file

Tags: c#, assemblyinfo

I have this problem:

```
Error   23  The "AssemblyInfo" task could not be loaded from the assembly AssemblyInfoTask, Version=1.0.51130.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35. Could not load file or assembly 'AssemblyInfoTask, Version=1.0.51130.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, and that the assembly and all its dependencies are available.  CustomActions
```

Any sugestions?

**Update #1** The Problem was ocured after copying project from SVN in my PC. Project is written in VS 2005. And I have installed VS 2005.

**Update #2** Having installed SP1 for VS2005, It is still not working.

**Update #3** I have changed lines in project file like this**

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />

<!--  <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)eService.VersionNumber.targets" />
-->
```

and it starts to work. So, as I see, the problem was in the eService.VersionNumber.targets file. All is working in another PC and the files exist.

Comment: Have you tried a clean and rebuild?

Comment: Have you deployed the AssemblyInfoTask assembly? Is this in debug or release code, running from visual studio or on a client machine?

Comment: now I am installing SP1 for VS 2005. after that I will try yours advises.

Comment: @ Albin Sunnanbo, what do you mean "Have you deployed the AssemblyInfoTask assembly" ?

Comment: It can't find AssemblyInfoTask.dll.  Where is it?

Comment: @Hans Passant In my prohect. I dont know why It can't be find.

Comment: @Sergii, hmm, that was in the case of a deployed app, but when I read your question again, it looks like an error message from Visual Studio, then that is not the case.

Comment: It does no good in your project, it needs to be copied to the bin\Debug folder.  Set its Copy Local property.

Answer (score 0):

Try go to solution explorer in Visual Studio, then open the references folder.
There you should find AssemblyInfoTask with a warning sign next to it.
Click the AssemblyInfoTask reference and check the properties window. There you can find the path where Visual Studio looks for the assembly.
Either make sure the AssemblyInfoTask assembly is where Visual Studio is looking, or remove the reference and add it again with a new correct path.
If this is an project reference you need to make sure that project is in your solution and that the build order is correct.